# WKWebView save to UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, wkwebview

I use the code below to save WKWebView into UIImage. But the problem is, more than 50% of the UIImage is blank/white space.

```
- (UIImage *)screenCapture {    
UIImage *image;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollView.contentSize, TRUE, 0.0f);
{
    CGPoint savedContentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
    CGRect savedFrame = self.scrollView.frame;

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    [self.scrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.scrollView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
    self.scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
}
UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
return image;
}
```

Does anyone have encountered the same problem? Any ideas for a workaround here?
I've also tried this: `[self.scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` but it is much worse, the UIImage is just plain white.

UPDATE:
Here's my sample captured UIImage. 
[Captured UIImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZSDv.png)

Comment: so you are basically creating a screenshot from the scroll view right?

Comment: yes, the scrollview property of wkwebview

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.frame.size);
[scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Now you have the image of the scrollview in viewImage.

Comment: then propably you need to screenshot the view instead of scrollview. Try view.layer

Comment: the view in the view.layer must be the view in your scrollview

Comment: still `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scrollView.frame.size);` ? or should I change it to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size);`?

Comment: you shouldnt change the scrollview.frame.size if you need the screenshot of the content present in the scrollview

Comment: Also, if didnt came as per your need, update your question with the screenshot!!!

Comment: I've added the screenshot.

Comment: is it not what you wanted?

Comment: Can you mention the scrollview frame size and the view frame size ?

Comment: I'm working on WKWebView, the size of that is same as `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size` while the size of scrollView property of the WKWebView depends on the webpage displayed